# How can I add vertical space to a horizontal list?

Tags: css, html-lists

I have an unordered list where the list items have been set to display:inline.
I love how it looks, however when the items wrap to the next line the vertical space overlaps between the items.

I tried setting the margin on li items, the ul items, and the div these items are contained in. The li items won't expand and they won't use the extra space I provide them through the div.

Here is a screenshot of what it currently looks like:
[image: A set of menu items that are vertically too close to each other]

HTML:

```
<div class="hometrailertypes">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="/utility/Box_Series">Box Series</a></li>
  <li><a href="/utility/Landscaper_Series">Landscaper Series</a></li>
  <li><a href="/utility/ATV/Utility_Series">ATV/Utility Series</a></li>
  <li><a href="/utility/Snowmobile_Hauler_Series">Snowmobile Hauler Series</a></li>
  <li><a href="/utility/Car_Hauler_Series">Car Hauler Series</a></li>
  <li><a href="/utility/Tandem_Flatbed_Series">Tandem Flatbed Series</a></li>
  <li><a href="/utility/Deckover_Series">Deckover Series</a></li>
  <li><a href="/utility/All_Purpose/Equipment_Floats">All Purpose/Equipment Floats</a></li>
  <li><a href="/utility/Dumps">Dumps</a></li>
  <li><a href="/utility/Mini_Series">Mini Series</a></li>
  <li><a href="/utility/Scissor_Lift_Series">Scissor Lift Series</a></li>
  <li><a href="/utility/Telescopic_Lift_Series">Telescopic Lift Series</a></li>
  <li><a href="/utility/Combo_Series">Combo Series</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hometrailertypes>ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.hometrailertypes>ul>li
{
    display: inline;
}
.hometrailertypes>ul>li>a
{
    padding: .2em .1em;
    background-color: #036;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.hometrailertypes>ul>li>a:hover
{
    background-color: #369;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Ya sorry about that. I edited it =P

Comment: All answers were solid. Thank you.
I tried inline-block, but I must have not tried actually adding margins at the same time... silly of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
.hometrailertypes>ul>li
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:2px 0px;
}
.hometrailertypes>ul>li>a
{
    padding: .2em .1em;
    background-color: #036;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/zTFbQ/1/).

Answer (score 3):

You should try `display:inline-block` instead of `inline`.

This way, items won't wrap to the next line and you won't have problems. Well, there will be some items in the first line, some in the second... but none of them will break because they will behave like blocks without a line break before and after.

Answer (score 2):

I would go like this :

```
.hometrailertypes>ul>li
{
    display:inline;
    line-height:24px; /*set your desired height that way*/
}
```

Besides what other answers say, i recommend keeping display `inline` since `inline-block` doesn't work in some "old" browsers, cf. http://caniuse.com/inline-block thus if you have an equivalent option, use `line-height` instead, that costs you nothing.

Comment: I appreciate the legacy answer. Cheers!